# Можно ли использовать for в render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу пройтись и данным и вывести все элементы. Но жалуется на `Data.paperId.length; i++` в чемс проблема?

```
  render() {
    const Data = this.state.Data;
    if (!Data) return <div>Loading</div>;
    let count = Data.paperId.length;
    console.log(count);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="list_papers">
          <h1>List papers</h1>
          {/* <div>{JSON.stringify(Data)}</div>; */}
          for (let i = 0; i < Data.paperId.length; i++) {
            <p>First Name: {Data.paperId[i].first_name}</p>
            <p>Last Name: {Data.paperId[i].last_name}</p>
            <p>Email: {Data.paperId[i].paper_email}</p>
            <p>Passworld: {Data.paperId[i].paper_parole}</p>
            <p>Position: {Data.paperId[i].paper_position}</p>
            <p>About: {Data.paperId[i].paper_about}</p>
            <p>Researc: {Data.paperId[i].paper_research}</p>  
          }
        </div>
        <div className="profile">
          <h1>Profile paper</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а как жалуется?

Comment: аа тьфу, используйте `map` вместо цикла

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: ну и вы забыли `{}`для кода указать

Comment: а зачем они `{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **React.js** все данные можно вывести с помощью функции `map`

*Вот пример на codesandbox: [ссылка](https://codesandbox.io/s/18jrq42427)*

Пример по Вашему коду:

```
  render() {
    const { Data } = this.state;
    if (!Data) return <div>Loading</div>;
    console.log(count);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="list_papers">
          <h1>List papers</h1>
          {Data.map((item, index) => (
             <div key={index}>
               <p>First Name: {item.first_name}</p>
               <p>First Name: {item.last_name}</p>
               /* и т.д. */
             </div>
           ));
          }
        </div>
        <div className="profile">
          <h1>Profile paper</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Подробнее о выводе данных в **React.js** Вы можете прочитать в [документации](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).